# Why is Hibernate not using the next sequence value in the sequence table?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

We have an entity Credentials that uses a sequence generator:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CREDENTIALS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CredentialsSequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "CREDENTIALS_SEQUENCE")
public class Credentials extends AbstractTraceable implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CredentialsSequenceGenerator")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

The problem we're having is in our tests. We load some data into the database using EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.addScript("..."), then in the test we try to create some objects. The first insert fails because the primary key has already been used:

```
15:54:02.777 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator - Sequence identifier
generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[0]]
15:54:02.779 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier:
1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
```

My underestanding is the SequenceGenerator for GenerationType.SEQUENCE uses a sequence table called "hibernate_sequences", with the following structure (this was generated by SchemaExport):

```
  create table hibernate_sequences (
     sequence_name varchar(255),
     sequence_next_hi_value integer 
  );
```

In our scripts we increment the sequence table:

```
insert into hibernate_sequences VALUES('CREDENTIALS_SEQUENCE', 13);
```

It appears Hibernate not using this table at all, as the first id it tries to use is 1.

Any ideas? Is this the wrong GenerationType?

Comment: A sequence generator uses a sequence, not a table. Turn on SQL logging, and you'll know which queries are executed by Hibernate

Comment: Got it. I don't know why the Hibernate SchemaExport was generating "hibernate_sequences". That confused me. It is not getting used at all. As you said the CREDENTIALS_SEQUENCE is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my script needs to update the sequence table CREDENTIALS_SEQUENCE. In HSQL that is done as follows:

```
alter sequence credentials_sequence restart with 13;
```

HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES is not used.

Comment: could you please tell me where you did this?